# How to create dynamic date with time stamp?

Tags: linux, unix, unix-timestamp

I am new to linux.
I have the below requirement.
Let us say, the datetime now is `2018-07-11 15:01:23`
I want to generate the new datetime stamp which should be equal to nearest value of hour which is multiplier of `8`.
example , using the below current date and time, the result should look like below:

```
startdate = 2018-07-11 00:00:00 &
enddate = 2018-07-11 08:00:00.
```

if my current datetime stamp is `2018-07-12 07:01:11`
the dates should look like the below :

```
startdate = 2018-07-11 16:00:00 &
enddate = 2018-07-12 00:00:00.
```

I want to automate the dates as per the above.
Thank you.

Comment: It seems to be working fine now: ftimestamp=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")  
echo $ftimestamp  
fhour=$(date +"%H")  
fminute=$(date +"%M")  
fsecond=$(date +"%S")  
echo $fhour  
echo $fminute  
echo $fsecond  
fmodular2=$((fhour%8))  
echo $fmodular2  
datesec="$(date '+%s' --date="$ftimestamp")"  
enddate=$(date --date="@$((datesec - (fmodular2*3600) - (fsecond*1) - (fminute*60)))" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  
echo $enddate  
startdate=$(date --date="@$((datesec - ((fmodular2+8)*3600) - (fsecond*1) - (fminute*60)))" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  
echo $startdate

Answer (score 0):

What you have done in comment section is inefficient i think because it calls the date command six times or maybe less than that.
What happens if the script is called a fraction of a second before midnight and the date changes between
setting the month and day?
Lets say the script was called at 2018-04-31 23:59:59, but the values assigned could amount to 2018-04-01 00:00:00.
The date that was wanted was 31 April 2018 23:59:59 or 1 May 00:00:00. 
And what the script can get is 1 April 2018 00:00:00. That’s a whole month off!
A better method is to get a single string from date and split it into its parts.

```
date=$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S)
time=${date#*T}
date=${date%T*}
year=${date%%-*}
daymonth=${date#*-}
month=${daymonth%-*}
day=${daymonth#*-}
hour=${time%%:*}
minsec=${time#*-}
minute=${minsec%-*}
second=${minsec#*-}
```

Now you can do the calculation like in your other part of the code.